# Kinect for Navigation on Erratic Robot

Tags: ros, kinect, erratic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a kinect fitted on an erratic robot base. So far I managed to get the kinect and base working separately in ROS using erratic_player and openni for kinect. I also tried kinect laser emulator provided by ardros and works nicely.

I had a look at tf and also tutorials however am a bit stuck on how to set up and link the kinect frame and erratic odometry frame onto a common frame for navigation stack.

I think I am missing something fairly basic which I cannot figure out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10240/kinect-for-navigation-on-erratic-robot/) by [roboviz](https://answers.ros.org/users/685/roboviz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen this tutorial: [Robot Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup)?

For your robot you basically need to provide two tfs: odom -> base_link (the odometry) and base_link -> base_laser (the laser/kinect position). For the latter you can use a static_transform_publisher.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roboviz](https://answers.ros.org/users/685/roboviz/) on 2011-06-13**:
Thanks for your answer. Yes I already had a look at Robot Setup tutorial and admittedly I got a bit lost there. This goes to show how beginner I am on ROS! I will give it another try and hopefully be able to create the TFs and link them as suggested.